# JMX : rmiPort and registryPort the same?

Tags: java, rmi, jmx

I'm trying to learn JMX as deep as possible.

I've read many blog posts about how to explicitly set the port numbers used by the JMX server. As you may be aware there are actually two ports required: One for the Registry and one for RMI protocol traffic. Recently I discovered [this blog post](http://dimovelev.blogspot.de/2013/10/out-of-box-jmx-over-firewall-in-hotspot.html) which suggests that the two ports can be set to the same so that you only have to punch one hole in the firewall. I must admit I thought it would never work. I was certain that it would create a "socket already bound" exception or something like that.  But it does work!

Questions:

1. Why does it work?  Why can the Registry live on the same port as is used rmi protocol traffic?
2. Given that this works why would I *ever* want them to be on different ports. (assuming always using Java7 latest)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All remote objects, including the Registry, exported from the same JVM can share the same port. This is a basic feature of RMI.

You would only want them on different ports if e.g. one used SSL and one didn't, or if they were in different JVMs

Comment: I understand what he's talking about. An RMI registry is just a remote object.

Comment: I can only repeat. It's been there since 1997, deep in RMI, for all end points. The Registry endpoint is no different from the others. I do this all the time. You don't seem to know anything about it.

Comment: So you've been able to make JMX client connections to a server over one port?  What service URL works for this?

Comment: I've been able to share 50,000 remote objects and a Registry on the same port. JMX is just a layer over RMI. There is no reason why this won't work.

Comment: After looking more closely at lsof output it does look like this works.  Thanks.  I didn't know you can map it to the same address.  I'll update the docs on my SimpleJMX library.  http://256.com/sources/simplejmx/

Comment: While I can get it to work when *not* using socket factories I'm unable to do so *with* socket factories. I get an "Address already in use" exception. Unfortunately I need to use socket factories because of multi-homed host.

Comment: Since this becomes too big to continue on this question I've started [a new one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21555710/rmi-and-jmx-socket-factories) which deals specifically with the issue of Socket Factories in the combined-port scenario.