# RMI and JMX Socket Factories

Tags: java, rmi, jmx

I'm trying to start an embedded JMX server in my java app. I want to use the same port for the RMI Registry and for the actual RMI traffic (or JMX traffic if you like). Apparently this is possible since the [RMI Registry is merely a Remote Object itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21535066/jmx-rmiport-and-registryport-the-same).

The added difficulty is that I need to use Socket Factories because I need to bind to a specific NIC.
I start off by:

```
int registryPort = 3012;
int jmxPort = 3012;    // use the same port
```

and here's my server socket factory. Pretty straight-forward stuff:

```
public class MyRMIServerSocketFactory implements RMIServerSocketFactory {

    private final InetAddress inetAddress;

    public MyRMIServerSocketFactory(InetAddress inetAddress) {
        this.inetAddress = inetAddress;
    }

    @Override
    public ServerSocket createServerSocket(int port) throws IOException {
        return new ServerSocket(port, 0, inetAddress);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 5;
        hash = 97 * hash + (this.inetAddress != null ? this.inetAddress.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final FlexibleRMIServerSocketFactory other = (FlexibleRMIServerSocketFactory) obj;
        if (this.inetAddress != other.inetAddress && (this.inetAddress == null || !this.inetAddress.equals(other.inetAddress))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }    
}
```

(the `equals()` and `hashCode()` are auto-generated by my IDE, don't get stuck on them)

I create the RMI Registry like this:

```
serverSocketFactory = new MyRMIServerSocketFactory(inetAddressBind);
LocateRegistry.createRegistry(
        registryPort,
        RMISocketFactory.getDefaultSocketFactory(),  // client socket factory
        serverSocketFactory // server socket factory
        );
```

and then on to creating the JMXConnectorServer:

```
JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL(
     "service:jmx:rmi://localhost:" + jmxPort + 
      "/jndi/rmi://:" + registryPort + "/jmxrmi");

Map env = new HashMap();
env.put(RMIConnectorServer.RMI_SERVER_SOCKET_FACTORY_ATTRIBUTE, serverSocketFactory);

connector = JMXConnectorServerFactory.newJMXConnectorServer(
                url, 
                env,
                ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer());

connector.start();
```

This results in a bind error on the `connector.start()` saying that the address is already in use.

If I skip using Socket Factories altogether:

```
LocateRegistry.createRegistry(registryPort);
```

and

```
JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL(
     "service:jmx:rmi://localhost:" + jmxPort + 
      "/jndi/rmi://:" + registryPort + "/jmxrmi");


connector = JMXConnectorServerFactory.newJMXConnectorServer(
                url, 
                null,
                ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer());

connector.start();
```

it works as expected, i.e. only a single port will be opened and no errors.

**Question: How to make the 'single-listening-port-scenario' work with Socket Factories ?**

#### UPDATE - FINAL SOLUTION

It works if you create the Registry with a null client socket factory, i.e.

```
LocateRegistry.createRegistry(
        registryPort,
        null,  // client socket factory (let it default to whatever RMI lib wants)
        serverSocketFactory // server socket factory
        );
```

I also had to set the [`java.rmi.server.hostname` System Property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/javarmiproperties.html) which I guess will often be the case in a scenario like mine.

Comment: You might consider using SimpleJMX which does a lot of this for you.  http://256.com/sources/simplejmx/

Comment: I would be glad to but last time I looked it didn't have the feature of using socket factories. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Background: Without Socket Factories RMI/JMX is kinda useless except on the simplest of networking setups. In a corporate world hosts are often multi-homed. That's why !  :-)

Comment: Ah interesting. I'll have to add that.

Comment: Why do you need to bind to a specific NIC?

Comment: I've added socket factories to SimpleJMX @nolan6000 but they suffer from the same limitation that you are having.  Let me know if you'd like me to spin a version out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work: you have a correct-looking equals() method in your ServerSocketFactory, which is the important bit. RMI does call that. However the same doesn't apply currently to your client socket factory. You need to pass `null` as the client socket factory, not `RMISocketFactory.getDefaultSocketFactory(),` as that gives you a `sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory,` which doesn't implement `equals()` for some reason. Or else your own implementation of `RMIClientSocketFactory` with a plausible `equals()` method.

So what is happening here is that RMI is comparing the CSFs first, and they are coming out unequal, so it doesn't even bother comparing the SSFs:

```
csf1.equals(csf2) && ssf1.equals(ssf2)
```

so it tries to create a new `ServerSocket` on the port you specifed, which is the same as the first port, so it fails.

You could add a shortcut at the beginning of equals that returns true if this == that.

Comment: Yeah for some reason the JMX code is calling `createServerSocket(...)` twice which fails on the 2nd bind.  I've not been able to figure out what is different when you don't use a custom socket factory @nolan6000.

Comment: Oh and it looks like it is not calling the `hasCode()` and `equals()` methods according to my debugger.

Comment: Well, I can tell you I've tried making the socket factory a bit more intelligent so that is safe keeps the sockets it has created. Then on the second call it will simply return the same socket as was created on the first call. This works as far as the server side is concerned (no errors on startup phase). But the client side fails miserably with "java.rmi.NoSuchObjectException: no such object in table" and the server side also gets "java.io.IOException: unknown transport op 116" at the time of the connect attempt.

Comment: I think I got it (following EJP's advice)  : set the client socket factory to null on the `createRegistry()` call.

Comment: @Gray. Let me know if you can reproduce my success. If so I'll put the little green check mark on EJP's answer.

Comment: +1 Yeah that seems to work for me too @nolan6000.  I missed that nugget in the middle of his answer.  I also had to add in a `System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", inetAddress.getHostAddress());` to the jmx server code.  You can do that from the command line of course.

Comment: And now that the client factory is null `equals(...)` is being called.  Interesting.

Comment: I also had to add `java.rmi.server.hostname` but I thought that one only controlled the 'call-me-back' address, i.e. the address embedded in the exported objects, so I didn't think it was related to the issue at hand.

Comment: @EJP. Thanks. You are THE rmi/jmx wizard.

Comment: @Gray and nolan6000 See edit. The default CSF doesn't implement `equals()` at all, so RMI saw the CSFs as being unequal, so it didn't even bother checking the SSFs. You are correct about java.rmi.server.hostname. [Disclaimer: I'm not really a JMX wizard but I do know RMI.]

Answer (score 0):

You should search for the JMXMP protocol, and for the jmxremote_optional.jar that contains it. This is a more controllable, more efficient protocol for JMX.